# How to Run Matlab installed on windows from Linux

Tags: matlab

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed on my computer. I have Matlab R2012a installed on Windows and I will like to Launch Matlab from Ubuntu. I can navigate to the matlab folder from windows but i do not know how to launch it.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You realize that there's likely a Linux version of Matlab on that same CD right? That's how it's usually distributed. It uses the same license. Running that under Wine is a bad idea, the thought of my workspace crashing while having a bunch of unsaved computations just isn't worth it to me. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible. The method you want to use (using a windows installed version) can only work if that program does not require register keys to function or a licence server to work (and matlab does).

You can ...

1. [run Matlab native under Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). Matlab claims to work under [Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and Debian 6](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/sysreq/current_release/linux.html) and up.

Other methods:

1. You can use Matlab through a virtual machine (virtual box or kvm for instance) but that requires a seperate install from your current windows one and it also requires lots of resources (/ram).
2. Some versions of matlab also work with [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=49).

The option of using a windows installed version native under Linux is out of the question though.